# Как сделать чтобы, в словаре правильно выстраивались значения с ключом

Tags: swift, словари

Как сделать чтобы,  в словаре правильно выстраивались значения с ключом

```
var z:[String: Int]=["vaz":1, "gaz":2, "laz":3] 
for (x, t) in z {
   print("\(x)=>\(t)")  
}
gaz=>2
vaz=>1
laz=>3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Словари в свифте (как и во многих других языках) неупорядочены. Соответственно порядок ключей не гарантирован.

Но вы можете отсортировать словарь, как и любую коллекцию (результат уже будет не словарём):

```
var z:[String: Int]=["vaz":1, "gaz":2, "laz":3] 
for (x, t) in z.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key }) {
   print("\(x)=>\(t)")  
}
```

```
gaz=>2
laz=>3
vaz=>1
```

Проверка: https://iswift.org/playground?RgfbXE&v=3

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за доброту !!!

Comment: @LifeБедняка: Пожалуйста! Рад, если помогло!

Comment: я начинающий swift программист, и мне некоторые вещи пока не понятны, вы не могли объяснить эти операторы подробно. (by: { $0.key < $1.key })

Comment: @LifeБедняка: Смотрите. Это замыкания/анонимные функции, такая крутая фича современных языков. Почитайте про них, например, [вот эту статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/241303/). Если вкратце: параметром в sort передаётся функция, которая зависит от двух параметров (они для краткости обозначены просто $0 и $1), и она сравнивает `$0.key` (то есть, свойство `key` у нулевого параметра) и `$1.key` (аналогично), и возвращает результат типа `Bool`.

Comment: @LifeБедняка: Обязательно прочитайте статью и разберитесь, без замыканий сейчас никуда. :)

Comment: про блоки, я знаю еще из ruby, я временно приостановил изучать ruby, сейчас я изучаю больше swift, изучал я ruby по книге Head First. Изучаем Ruby классная книга!!!  пожалуйста объясните что за оператор   by: ?

Comment: @LifeБедняка: это не оператор, это имя параметра. Параметр называется `by`, вот тут это имя и указано. Это фича ещё из Objective C.

Comment: тойсь если это имя параметра, я могу его назвать не by а как-то под другому  ? например go

Comment: @LifeБедняка: Ну если вы пишете сами функцию, вы называете её параметры как хотите. Если функцию пишет кто-то другой, как с функцией `sort`, то он придумывает название как хочет.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, если что я к вам обращусь, просто сейчас сложно переключатся с ruby мышления на swift мышления, спасибо вам еще раз )

Comment: @LifeБедняка: Ruby и Swift достаточно близки, так что вам не составит большого труда привыкнуть. Удачи!

Comment: я создал блок на swift var z={(str:String)->String in 
print(str)
return "Hello \(str)"
}
z("Mir")  но компилер ругается так   /swift-execution/Sources/main.swift:8:1: warning: result of call is unused, but produces 'String'
z("Mir")
^~~~~~~~

Comment: Ну да, он же вас предупреждает: `z` возвращает `String`, а вы его не используете.

Comment: как не использую объясните пожалуйста

Comment: @LifeБедняка: Ну, функция возвращает значение. А вы это значение игнорируете. Об этом вас и предупреждает компилятор.

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста зачем нужен это оператор ? Void если не правильно называю извините пожалуйста

Comment: я переписал программу, стало еще хуже ( var z:String ={(str:String)->String in
print(str)
return "Hello \(str)" }
z("Mir")